# only load model when i open developer toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Now I have a little issue when I open a three.js mesh. When I open the webpage with chrome or firefox (didn't try IE), all is ok but the canvas don't appear.

I must activate the developer toolbar to see the three.js mesh.

**Webpage code**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TFG: Pagina web con webGL sobre brazos roboticos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<script src="libs/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//use.edgefonts.net/cabin;source-sans-pro:n2,i2,n3,n4,n6,n7,n9.js"></script>

<!--Slipry-->
<script src="libs/slippry/dist/slippry.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/slippry/dist/slippry.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
<!--Bibliotecas-->
<script src="libs/ThreeJSV71/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="libs/Coordinates.js"></script>
<script src="libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/stats.min.js"></script>   
<script src="libs/ColladaLoader.js"></script>   



<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getScript("js/json.js", function(){
            $( "#go" ).click(function() {           
        })});           

        <!--Slipry-->
        var slide = $('#slider2').slippry();
    });     
</script>   





<font size="+6"><b>TFG</b></font><br>
<a href="../index.html">Volver a atrás</a>

<form name="framecombo">
<select name="framecombo2" size=1>
    <option value='blender/json/camara'>camara</option>
    <option value='blender/json/avenger'>Avenger</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" id="go" value="Go!" onclick="setURL(framecombo2.value)"></p>
</form>
<hr></hr>
<section class="wrapper">
    <ul id="slider2">
        <li><img src="images/1.png" />  </li>
        <li><img src="images/2.png" />  </li>
        <li><img src="images/3.png" />  </li>
        <li><img src="images/4.png" />  </li>
        <li><img src="images/KL250-3.png"/> </li>
        <li><img src="images/KL250-3claw.png" />    </li>
    </ul>
</section>

<hr>
<div id='container' width=800, height=600>  
</div>
<br>
```

**javascript code**

```
var width = window.innerWitdh,
height = window.innerHeight,
clock = new THREE.Clock(),
scene,
camera,
renderer,
ambientLight,
directionalLight,
loader,
modelo = new THREE.Object3D(),
cameraConmtrols,
URL;

init();
animate();  


function init()
{
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize(width,height); 
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x0000AA),1.0);
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene =new THREE.Scene();
var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, aspectRatio,0.1,100);
camera.position.set(0,5,30);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(ambientLight);

directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0);
scene.add(directionalLight);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10,1));
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();    

cameraControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
cameraControls.target.set(0,0,0);
window.addEventListener('resize',updateAspectRatio);


}

function updateAspectRatio()
{
//Renovar las dimensiones del renderer
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
//Renovar la relacion de aspecto de frutum
camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
function animate() {

requestAnimationFrame( animate );   

renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function setURL(url)
{
//window.stop()
URL = url+'/model.json';    

loader.load(URL, function(geometry,materials)
{
    //Cargamos el modelo
    modelo = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));


    //Cargamos el archivo de configuracion del modelo
    //------------------------------------

    $.get(url+'/config.cfg', function(result) 
    {
        var txt=result.split('\n');
        var pos=txt[2].split(':')[1].split(',');
        var rot=txt[3].split(':')[1].split(',');            
        var sca=txt[4].split(':')[1].split(',');

        modelo.position.set(parseInt(pos[0]),parseInt(pos[1]),parseInt(pos[2]));
        modelo.scale.set(parseInt(sca[0]),parseInt(sca[1]),parseInt(sca[2]));
    });

    //------------------------------------

    scene.add(modelo);      
});
```

}

The code is inefficient. The project is in his first steps. 
What I am doing wrong? I dont want to open developer tool to see the mesh.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 similar issues as the one you are describing. I wanted to slide/fade an element that was positioned as fixed, and some of the elements inside of them did not show until I opened the developer tools or interacted with the DOM somehow. I did not find a fix yet, but I can tell you the root cause is animating the elements. My workaround was removing those animations and simply toggle a class to show/hide the element.

Try using two classes:

```
.show {
    display: block; //Or fixed or absolute or whatever you need here.
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

And instead of sliding/fading just toggle those classes to hide and show the element and check if your problems are gone.

Hope this helps to tackle down your issues.

Comment: Sorry, nothing change

Comment: Did you remove var slide = $('#slider2').slippry()? I believe that is using some css transitions as well.

Comment: Yes it use css transitions but nothing change if i remove it. Sorry